# search a specific string pattern and replace it with lower case recursively

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have to search for the string which contains `Aaa*.c` and replace it with `aaa*.c` in a file recursively.

I have hundreds of files in a directory which contains the specific pattern (this .c can be an extension to the string or in between  the string too) and i have to replace such string in lower case

I am trying to use awk '{print tolower($0) or tr but could not search for a specific pattern and apply here.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *"this .c can be an extension to the string or in between the string too"*

Answer (score 5):

Since you put Perl in the list of tags, here is a Perl solution

```
perl -pe "s/(\S+\.c)\b/\L$1/g" myfile > newfile
```

If you want to edit the file in-place (and lose the original)

```
perl -pie "s/(\S+\.c)\b/\L$1/g" myfile
```

---

To rename all *.c files in the current directory, write

```
perl -e "rename $_, qq(\L$_) for glob '*.c'"
```

---

To do this recursively through all subdirectories, do this

```
perl -MFile::Find -e "find sub{ rename $_, qq(\L$_) if /\.c$/i }, '.'"
```

Comment: Thanks but m still confused a little. 
I want to modify all the files in a directory which contains a string of pattern ending with .c (it can be like all strings containing ABC has to replaced to strings which has abc in between)

Comment: Ah I see, I think! You want to *rename* all *.c files to lower case? I have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: ... and you mention *recursively*. Does that mean you want to do the same thing for all subdirectories? I've added to the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed for this.

```
(echo AaA.c; echo bGb) | sed '/\.c$/y/A-Z/a-z/'
```

Output:

```
aaa.c
bGb
```

Answer (score 0):

here if script will create new file with existing file but the files with *.c will be replaced with lowercase leteters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $file='originalfile.txt';
open(CMD,  "<$file") or die "$!";

my $str;
while(<CMD>) {

    if($_ =~ /\.c$/){

        $str.=lc($_);
    } else {
        $str.=$_;
    }

 }
 print $str;
 close(CMD);
 my $file2='newfile.txt';
 open(CMD,  ">$file2") or die "$!";
 print CMD $str;
 close(CMD);
```

let me know if above is correct to your needs.

Comment: This script is helpful for one file but I have hundreds of files which contain strings having .c as common. I need to replace all such string with lower case. 

Thanks

Comment: do you want me to modify the above code for you 100s of file?, if so can you please let me know are all your 100s files remain in same directory? and you want to replace the file content with above requirement without creating new file?

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "Aa.c bB.b CC.c" | perl -ne 's/\b(\w+)(?=\.c)\b/lc $1/eg;print;'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "Aa.c bB.b CC.c\ndD.d EEE.ca Ff_gG.c" | sed 's/\S*\.c\>/\L&/g'
aa.c bB.b cc.c
dD.d EEE.ca ff_gg.c
```

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you want to rename files. If so, you could do it as follows:

```
find -name 'Aaa*.c' -type f | perl -nle'
   my $o=$_; my $n=lc($_);
   next if $n eq $o;
   if (-e $n) {
      warn "$o -> $n: Rename failed: Already exists\n";
   } elsif (!rename($o, $n)) {
      warn "$o -> $n: Rename failed: $!\n";
   }
'
```

Or using just Perl,

```
perl -MFile::Find::Rule -e'
   for my $o (
      File::Find::Rule->name("Aaa*.c")->file->in(".")
   ) {
      my $n=lc($_);
      next if $n eq $o;
      if (-e $n) {
         warn "$o -> $n: Rename failed: Already exists\n";
      } elsif (!rename($o, $n)) {
         warn "$o -> $n: Rename failed: $!\n";
      }
   }
'
```

Comment: I've lost many files by accidentally renaming multiple files to the same name. I consider the `-e $n` check to be of utmost importance.